# having trouble making a menu slide down on click and then reverse this animation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a sliding menu effect when a link is clicked, basically on click I want to prepend a background that fades in with 0.6 opacity and then slide my menu into place and then on a further click I want to reverse this animation. I have create a click event with a callback function but I think this callback is cancelling out my first click so nothing seems to be happening, can anyone advise me on how I can create this effect?

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AHj4Y/3/

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: Save the fiddle and link again to it.

Comment: sorry http://jsfiddle.net/AHj4Y/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works the way you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/AHj4Y/5/